# bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create

Tags: sublimetext2

why my sublime text giving me warning: bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create

although it is building and running the code correctly.

Please help me  just got irritated by seeing this warning.

I have searched the whole web but i couldn't find any solution

Answer (score 25):

This error message is misleading. At least for me it did not solve the problem after creating /tmp directory. Problem was solved after I killed sh.exe.

Comment: I tried this, it's the right answer and it worked for me. I hope who asked the question can come back to accept the answer.

Comment: Nice find, this worked for me when sourcetree was giving me the same error.

Comment: No such process on my machine... Still happens

Comment: Same for me as with Gulzar, no sh.exe present in the task manager (looked carefully at every running process).

Comment: How do you kill _sh.exe_, is it a service or process? I mean can we open Task-Manager and kill process/service named _sh.exe_?
I tried it but could not find _sh.exe_. I am actually trying to install Jekyll on Windows 10.

Answer (score 15):

To piggyback on Kode Charlie's answer:

Open Start Menu

Type "cmd"

Press Enter

type "bash"

Press Enter

type "mkdir /tmp"

Press Enter

Close the command prompt window

Solved the error for me in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: You're my hero !

Answer (score 15):

In my case I am using windows. My solution was:

1. Find "bash.exe" at git folder installation - default is
   "C:\Program Files\Git\bin";
2. Double click bash.exe;
3. At the command line type: mkdir /tmp

And done.

Comment: I was seeing this message while using Git Bash as my default terminal in VS Code for Windows. Following these steps solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clue - I had the same issue but in my case I had proactively uninstalled git/git-bash in Windows (in favour of WSL) and so the error message was just reminding me that I should use a different shell that is actually installed. I couldn't create a directory or run any commands because none were installed :-)

Answer (score 8):

Try opening a bash-shell, and then:

```
$ mkdir /tmp
```

See if that makes the warning go away.

Comment: plz describe the method. i'm a beginner

Comment: I dont use git bash. I use command prompt. The fix for me was launching git bash from start menu, which opens a different terminal (git bash terminal). That session will start in a location. That location was missing the /tmp folder. Once I added the /tmp folder to the git bash default launch location, my command prompt sessions stopped throwing the warning.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Git for Windows, just create the directory:
C:\Program Files\Git\tmp

Answer (score 3):

Rebooting Windows fixed it for me.

Comment: This was what also worked in my case, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Necros answer, Not all windows 10 builds even come with bash

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a harmless error that can be ignored. It also occurs when your /tmp/ is a mount to %TEMP%

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin>.\env bash
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
bash: __git_ps1: command not found

/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin
```

So for instance, you may get this error if you have a bash script with a shebang
`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Answer (score 1):

Although not SublimeText related, I had this warning when running make.exe from a "Git Bash" environment.

The cause ? Due to search path ordering, a different sh.exe was being executed. (I.e. not in /usr/bin)

```
$ sh
$ ps -s
   4348 pty1     09:48:42 /usr/bin/ps
   4836 pty1     09:48:40 /c/Users/Nigel/bin/sh
   4400 pty1     09:48:36 /usr/bin/bash
   4596 ?        09:48:36 /usr/bin/mintty
   4808 ?        09:36:14 /usr/bin/mintty
    512 pty0     09:36:14 /usr/bin/bash
```

After deleting the unwanted left-over C:\Users\Nigel\bin\sh.exe; the warning no longer appears.