# git fetch - bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create

Tags: git, bash

I'm running `git fetch` and am getting this error:

```
> git fetch
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
```

Note that I have already

- got a `C:/tmp`
- set ENV vars set for TEMP / TMP to `C:/tmp`
- read [bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492715/bash-exe-warning-could-not-find-tmp-please-create)

Any suggestions why this has suddenly stopped working. It was working yesterday!

Note: I get the same error with both `git bash` and `Powershell`.

==== UPDATE

And for completeness here are the env variables as output by Powershell

```
> dir env:TEMP

Name                           Value
----                           -----
TEMP                           C:\tmp\


> dir env:TMP

Name                           Value
----                           -----
TMP                            C:\tmp\
```

Comment: You can `stat /tmp` from git bash? (I don't know where it is looking for powershell.) You also have whatever directories you have `TEMP` and `TMP` set to?

Comment: $ stat
sh.exe": stat: command not found

Comment: This works for me all the time.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33220984/965873

Answer (score 2):

This was seen when the path including some non-ascii character (see [git-for-windows/git/issues/331](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/331)

Make sure the issue persists with the [latest git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (unzip [PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add its `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\usr\bin` folder to `%PATH%`)

Check if the issue persists when the fetch is done form a regular CMD session (not powershell or bahsh).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the TEMP environment (my Computer> Advanced > Environment Variables) Was somehow garbled (git bin was appenend (?))

Setting it to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp fixed it